# Can I lock vector art EPS10 files to avoid editing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, save

I read somewhere that it is possible to save an illustrator file as a .eps file and have no layer editing options? So the art is scaleable but not editable?

I have tried but can't seem to find anything? Did I misread and this isn't possible and all .eps single layer files are editable i.e. change colour scheme and alter original vector design.

I don't know if i'm am missing something really obvious but if someone could help explain the process and offer any help, I would greatly appreciated it. Thanks.

Just to clarify I am currently working in Illustrator CS5.

Comment: Changed the question to make it more specific and the link above doesn't answer the question, But would really appreciate an answer.

Comment: I think what you heard about is **locking a layer** before saving (in Illustrator, click the space by the layer so it shows a padlock). It's not a security thing - not all software respects it and any anyone can turn it off and unlock the layers very easily. It's more of a way of *discouraging* editing, e.g. helping people to not accidentally edit the wrong thing when editing a template. Or, as a way of saying "No, *seriously*, DON'T mess around with this logo" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not "lock" Illustrator files. Any vector art is always edit able to a degree. You can purposely expand and flatten artwork to make editing difficult, but you can not prevent all editing.

Comment: So in the scenario of selling vector artwork would it better to use EPS10 a single layered file and expand everything so its harder to edit or should I try and make it as easy as possible for people to edit. (I know its a bit off topic but would really appreciate a response, i'm pretty new at all this)

Comment: @Hunter I don't think it's offtopic. It's something lots of designers face, so I'd actually consider changing the question to something in the lines of "Should I block my vector art for selling?"

Comment: @Hunter it is entirely up to you what you sell. From a marketing standpoint, this would be something a company tests. They would offer both options (unknown to customers) and then see which files sell better and which customers return to purchase more. From an artists perspective, I always my my vectors as difficult as possible to edit. I sell art, not infinitely editable vector files.

Comment: As I've posted before, I think you're simply reinventing the wheel. No matter how talented you are no one will find you without you spending thousands on advertising. You'll be competing with well established artist all over the world selling at both major and micro-stock sites. But it's your venture :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So glad I found this site. I have noticed you have commented and answered a few of my questions so thank you very much really helps me out. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, its a portfolio as well as practice actually making a site and you make a good point, I may divide my artwork between my own site and somewhere like 'graphic river'.

Comment: For what it's worth, some ability to lock editing in Illustrator files has been requested as a feature for Illustrator for a number of years. However, its impossible to say if Adobe can or will ever implement such a feature.

Answer (score 2):

I know this doesnt answer you question about EPS, but you can prevent editing in PDFs!
In my opinion its the best format to hand over artwork anyway.

[image]

Comment: Yeah but I was hoping to keep it vector, so that I could still scale the art but it not be editable but if I didn't need the scaling aspect this would have worked. Thanks for pointing this out. is this screenshot from CS6? Does CS5 have all these options as well??

Comment: @Hunter PDFs are usually vector (except where raster graphics are placed in them). PDFs can also be placed as embedded vectors in other artwork, so they're ideal for cases where you're sending wholly finalised graphics and you don't care about them being easy to edit (e.g. they're the standard for sending something to print, or sending an advert to be placed in a magazine layout). They're less common for stock vectors in my experience because people usually buy stock vectors *in order to* edit them, and PDFs aren't designed to be easy to edit.

Comment: PDF might not be a good format for stock assets tough. Besides its pretty easy to circumvent the editing restriction, just dump the data to a virtual printer then let ghostscript rebuild it to eps.